# how to parse the following string using regular expression (JS)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string: `"bytes 5242880-5253879/5253880"`

I need to take parse the string and extract the numbers using regexp in JS, thanks

Comment: Please show your efforts, SO is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite vague but the following regex will match each number (separated by the dash and forward slash) in groups 1..3:

```js
const str = "bytes 5242880-5253879/5253880"
let n = str.match(/bytes (\d.*)-(\d.*)\/(\d.*)/)
console.log("Match 1:", n[1])
console.log("Match 2:", n[2])
console.log("Match 3:", n[3])
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just match the numbers with `\d+`.

```js
let str = "bytes 5242880-5253879/5253880"
let n = str.match(/\d+/g)
console.log(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

`string input = "bytes 5242880-5253879/5253880";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?:^|)(\d{7,8})(?!\d)", "");
Console.WriteLine(result); // >> 524288052538795253880`

[image]